# Add button under CKEditor is not visible

Tags: javascript, html, django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I have used **CKEditor django plugin** in my **form modal**. But when i try to **show ADD button** below the CKEditor, the button doesn't appear in the UI at all.

As shown in the below image, I have currently kept the **Add button on the top of the CKEditor text box** as its not appearing when placed at the bottom.

[image]

**Below is the HTML code snippet**

```
   <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="">Driver Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dn" id="dnn" required="True" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="st">Driver Description</label>
              <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1"></textarea>
              <script>
                  CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
              </script>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary up">
                ADD
              </button>
            </div>

          </div>
   </div>

<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.6/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Can someone please suggest how to make the add button make it appear below ckeditor.

Comment: Your button is probably being hidden beneath the Editor. If you give the editor1 textarea a height in css, you should be able to push the "Add" button below the editor textarea, and visible.

Comment: When i do inspect element, the button div is not visible at all....strange!

Comment: Try commenting out `CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );` and if you should then be able to see your button. Once you adjust the css moving the button lower, then uncomment that line and your button should be visible because you had moved it down far enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap 4, You can use the [Order](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#order) feature if your elements are wrapped inside a flex container.

Your code should look similar to this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="col-md-12">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Driver Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          name="dn"
          id="dnn"
          required="True"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="st">Driver Description</label>
        <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1"></textarea>
        <script>
          CKEDITOR.replace("editor1");
        </script>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer order-1">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary up">
          ADD
        </button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.6/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
```